# How to calculate lambda for Box-CoX in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, lambda, normalization

I'm trying to normalize my distribution and want to use Box-Cox Transformation. The problem is the data set is huge and my notebook crashes every time I do it. So, I have to do it in SQL Server. I have found a function https://www.itprotoday.com/development-techniques-and-management/box-cox-transformation-calculating-medians-and-quartiles that can calculate the Box-Cox Transformation but I need to calculate the appropriate lambda value.

Does anyone have any insight as to how we can calculate the optimal lambda value for Box-Cox in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So your notebook (Jupyter I assume) can't handle the data volume but SQL Server can? Is this where you got your function? https://www.itprotoday.com/development-techniques-and-management/box-cox-transformation-calculating-medians-and-quartiles and you want to find the optimal lambda value?

Comment: Hi, @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the quick response. Yes, I got my function from the link you mentioned and, yes I would like to find the optimal lambda value. Also lastly yes my SQL Server can handle the volume but Jupyter can't

Comment: I can't answer your question. I do suggest that you create a free cloud account with someone like AWS or Azure and use their compute to do what you need to do as you should be able to run your calcs within free account terms, plus you get to learn about cloud. Both platforms have Databricks, which is probably the easiest platform to get started on

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid this is for a client's project and I cannot connect to anything except SQL Server and Python as the VM provided does not have an internet connection and I cannot install anything or connect to anything except what already on the system. Thanks for the help though.